# java calling Logger class in other classes

Tags: java, logging

I wrote a separate class MyLogger with static method

```
static public void setup(String className, Exception e, Level level) {

    System.out.println("className = " + className);
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(className);
    logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);



    try {
        fileTxt = new FileHandler("Logging.%u.%g.txt",1024 * 1024, 10, true );
        // create a TXT formatter
        formatterTxt = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);

        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);
        logger.log(level, e.toString(), e);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        System.out.println("SecurityException ");
        Logger logger2=Logger.getLogger(MyLogger.class.getName());
        logger2.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
        logger2.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

This static method receives a string className which I put as a parameter into Logger.getLogger().

In another class I call MyLogger.setup(CommonFrame.class.getName(), e, Level.SEVERE).
Everything works. But the problem is that in the file I get "May 25, 2014 2:05:30 PM javagui.MyLogger setup" and I thought that it should be instead like this "May 25, 2014 2:05:30 PM javagui.CommonFrame" because I assigned that name to the logger.
Am I right? If yes, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have use the [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format%28java.util.logging.LogRecord%29) property of the [java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html) to use the [logger name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getLoggerName%28%29) instead of the [source classname](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html#getSourceClassName%28%29).

Modify your launch script to set the following system property:

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="%1$tc %3$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n"
```

Or modify your logging.properties to include:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tc %3$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n
```

Otherwise, you can create a custom [formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Formatter.html) and use that extract the [information](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogRecord.html) you want to see in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [log(LogRecord)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.LogRecord-) method and specify the class name.

```
static public void setup(String className, Exception e, Level level) {

    [...]

    try {
        [...]
        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);
        LogRecord record = new LogRecord(level, e.toString());
        record.setThrown(e);
        record.setSourceClassName(className);
        record.setSourceMethodName("");
        logger.log(record);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        [...]
    }

}
```