# How to specify a logging level for a single class

Tags: java, logging, log4j, java.util.logging

I have an ant target that calls multiple classes to do multiple things. It uses the "logging.properties" file to define the logging levels and handlers.

```
handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=logs/ant-logging.log

# Write 10MB before rotating this file
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit=10000000

# Number of rotating files to be used
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count=4
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

.level=INFO
```

Now one of the java files it calls is taking a huge chunk of time to complete. I don't have access to this class, so I want to set a specific logging level for that specific class to try to understand what's wrong with my implementation.

I don't want to change the global logging level, I just want to add a specific level to a certain class, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Logging levels are specified for logger names.  Depending on how the application is written in general, the logger name might have the same name as the class or it will use some module name

In your properties file, you can specify the [name of the logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html):

> All properties whose names end with ".level" are assumed to define log levels for Loggers. Thus "foo.level" defines a log level for the logger called "foo" and (recursively) for any of its children in the naming hierarchy.Log Levels are applied in the order they are defined in the properties file. Thus level settings for child nodes in the tree should come after settings for their parents. The property name ".level" can be used to set the level for the root of the tree.

For example:

```
foo.level=FINE
```

If you don't know the name of the logger you can use simple formatter to [capture the logger name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23853449/java-calling-logger-class-in-other-classes/23893329#23893329) of the loggers that are logging messages.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe you can specify by class and log to its own specific appender

For example let's say your class is `com.test.FaultyClass`

Then you can put

```
log4j.logger.com.test.FaultyClass=DEBUG, myappender
```

This will enforce that the output of FaultyClass will not show up in the other appenders

```
log4j.additivity.com.test.FaultyClass=false
```

Now you setup `myappender` however you like

```
log4j.appender.myappender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.myappender.datePattern='-'dd'.log'
log4j.appender.myappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```